# How to get the result of the inner function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi in below code i need to get the result of the fun1.How to get that result of that function.

```
 var s=function() {
   var val = 1;
   return {
      fun1:function(){
         return val;
      }
   }
 };
```

Now im doing like below.is it correct or any other way to do this.

```
 alert(s().fun1());
```

if the above method is correct means
why we re changing to the below format

```
var s=(function() {
   var val = 1;
   return {
      fun1:function(){
        return val;
       }
   }
})();


alert(s.fun1());
```

Comment: That's correct. What's your doubt?

Comment: well yes that's ok but it seems weird that you have to instanciate an anonymous `s()` for each function call. I'd use an intermediary object instead.

Comment: Your code will work. I assume your actual code is more complicated.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? We need more info to determine if that's the right way to do the specific task are trying to accomplish. But the code itself is correct.

Comment: Congratulations you made a _private_ variable :D

Comment: @Viclib pls see my updated info..

Comment: This is called the *module pattern*. Please read this: http://briancray.com/posts/javascript-module-pattern

Comment: @JoeFrambach ok i will go through the given link

Comment: @sachin well it's pretty much the same, the only difference is that the second version stores the result of s() and then calls fun1. If you were to call fun1 again, the second version would be obviously faster because you don't have to call s() again. This looks like the module pattern, so if `s` is actually a big module, it obviously doesn't make sense to call it more than once! In other words, `s.fun1()` just calls fun1() from an already-defined module, while `s().fun1()` builds the whole module and then calls fun1()!